# Evil eyesight or dṛṣṭidōṣa

Tags: belief, superstitions

Firstly, is it true that somebody bad intentions can cause trouble and hindrance into others life?

How can lemon/chilli/salt/red brown or black beads worn in wrist keep us away from the evil eyesight?

Comment: 'Nazar' is an Arabic word. I would use the term 'Drishtidosham'.

Comment: Suggestion: Could you edit the title to Drishti dosha as suggested? "Buri Nazar" in particular refers to the turkish belief of evil eye.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but it is peripheral:

> "Many times, I have been asked, what to do if someone has cast an “evil
>   eye” on me.
>
> The first thing to do is to not bother about it. Gurudev had once
>   said, this is all simply on the periphery and will just vanish in no
>   time. He said any sort of “curse” is always peripheral and will go
>   away very fast. However, a blessing comes from deep within and will
>   stay for a very long time!
>
> Having said this, there are a few things you can do if you are feeling
>   that you are the victim of an evil eye. Typically you will see that
>   for absolutely no reason, you are being unwell, losing money, having
>   minor accidents, friends not talking to you, etc. It could of course
>   mean you have been in too many polluted places, too many shopping
>   malls or are being careless and simply not being nice to people around
>   you. However if that’s not the case, then it could be some petty
>   jealousy of someone has rubbed off on you and you have become the
>   victim of an “evil eye”.
>
> Super regular Sadhana, Seva and Satsang will blow anything negative
>   away from you! Go for a dip in the sea. Or take a full body bath with
>   salt water few times a week. Get someone, typically an elder woman (it
>   works great with younger ones as well) to do the nullifying the evil
>   eye ceremony on you (Nazar uttarna). Or go to a priest you know well
>   and ask him to do it for you...."

You can read more here: http://bawandinesh.name/the-evil-eye/

Also, lemon, chilli etc do not work. Salt does as mentioned (dip in the sea). Is is said that the salt crystals have a cleansing frequency. I am not sure if any research has been done on that.