# What is the significance of tying a string of lemon and chillies?

Tags: belief, superstitions

We will see Chilli and lemon hanging on a string over doorways everywhere. This is called "Nimbu Mirchi Totka" in Hindi.

[image: Nimbu Mirchi string]

Image Credits : Google Images

What do our Hinduism say about this belief? What is the significance of this?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate [Evil eyesight or buri nazar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11326/3500)

Comment: These are not just superstitions as some people mite think.. There are plenty of such remedies that are said to remove evil eye given in some not so well known Tantras like Shabar Tantra, Indrajalam etc... If these remedies are not already found in some scriptures or the other then we could not have discovered them coz we don't have such imaginative powers or skills.. But at the same time it is not easy to answer it because of lack of references.. So I think ur bounty mite be wasted here..

Comment: There is a legend  associated with this . Its believed that hanging  Lemon-Chilli at  doorstep or on vehicles keeps "Alaxami" twin sister of Laxmi from entering inside to avoid misfortune or financial losses at the place of business. As this thing is not mentioned in any of the scripture , providing the answer is bit more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain energies that are not perceived by our senses, but actually affect us. Every thought about any person, reaches him subconsciously, it requires a great deal of effort and spiritual progress to perceive them. Many a times people think negatively about us or our belongings aware or unaware.

Substances like lemon, chillies, crystal salt, camphor etc. have the capacity to remove these energies by absorbing them into their interstices and diffusing it into another medium like air, water etc., and these media being natural are storehouses of infinite energy regardless of its nature. Thus such substances are used to purify or rather decontaminate the source it is intended for.

Comment: Actually while answering we need to cite some sources to back up our claims that we make in the answers.. This gives the answer some authority.. sources allowed are  scriptures like Vedas, Upanishads, Smritis, Puranas, etc .. sources can also be works of Acharayas, Saints (like say Swami Vivekananda) .. answers without any sources are just our opinions and such answers are likely to deleted as well ..

Comment: What about opinions? Where to post those? Many times an opinion may remind or point another person towards an authoritative answer and the other person can then post a real answer with sources.