# Scriptural mentions of the ability of other people to influence your life trajectory by being envious of you, what is the remedy?

Tags: belief

My mother would always say, 'Don't show off too much, other people being envious will ensure you don't prosper'. I know rishis in Treta Yuga have gotten into spats with other individuals and cursed misfortune upon people! (An example being Karna).

Are there scriptural mentions where people just being envious of other people's accomplishments completely destroyed their life?

Comment: This is only a Q&A site. Please do not ask personal advice questions or suggestions in your questions. No one here is a guru. Just users like you.

Comment: I'll alter my question then to just know if there are scriptural mentions of folks simply thinking enviously and that causing things to manifest

Comment: Already asked. Possible duplicate of [Evil eyesight or buri nazar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11326/5212) and [Is Dristhi (Evil Eye) Pottu,Photos and other activities are said in our scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17101/5212)

Comment: Ohh.. Feel free to close it